# How to create CSRF token for Cakephp 3 PHPunit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, csrf, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to get my unit tests working again after enabling CSRF tokens and SSL in my CakePHP 3 app.

How do I create or generate a token for a test like the following? Or do I just disable it for testing purposes?

```
public function testLogin() {
    $this->get('/login');
    $this->assertResponseOk();

    $data = [
        'email' => 'info@example.com',
        'password' => 'secret'
    ];
    $this->post('/login', $data);

    $this->assertResponseSuccess();
    $this->assertRedirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'dashboard']);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official documentation [has good approach since version 3.1.2](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-actions-protected-by-csrfcomponent-or-securitycomponent).

You only have to call `$this->enableCsrfToken();` and/or `$this->enableSecurityToken();` before your post to be able to perform the request successfully with token.

As the official example shows:

```
public function testAdd()
{
    $this->enableCsrfToken();
    $this->enableSecurityToken();
    $this->post('/posts/add', ['title' => 'Exciting news!']);
}
```